# What's wrong in my solution and pls provide the correct one in this question of finding range

Tags: functions

> Find the range of the function $$y=\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)(x+3)}}{x+2}$$

**My attempt:**
$$y=\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)(x+3)}}{x+2}$$
$$\implies x^2(y^2-1)+x(4y^2-2)+4y^2+3=0$$
Since $x\in\mathbb{R}$ so roots can't be complex $\implies \Delta\ge0$
$$(4y^2-2)^2-4(y^2-1)(4y^2+3)\ge0$$
$$\implies \frac{-2}{\sqrt3}\le y\le\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$$

But this isn't the answer. What's wrong$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming that$$y=\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)(x+3)}}{x-2}\iff y^2=\frac{(x-1)(x+3)}{(x-2)^2}?$$

Comment: @AnotherUser yess

Comment: As an indication that things have indeed gone wrong, suppose $x\approx 2$. Then the numerator is approximately $\sqrt{5}$ but the denominator is some small quantity. Hence their ratio can be made arbitrarily large, so the range will not be a finite interval.

Comment: @Semiclassical range is a finite interval according to wolframalpha

Comment: Not according to what I plugged into WA (“range of sqrt((x-1)(x+3))/(x-2)”).

Comment: Oh sorry @Semiclassical

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: You are assuming that $x$ can take any real value ; **this is not the case** : values of $x$ in $(-3,1)$ have to be excluded in order we can take the square root.

Comment: By the unfortunately hyper-ambiguous word "range" of a function f, can we assume that you mean the set of all f(x) such that f(x) makes sense (as a real number)?   (A better word for that is the *image* of f, notated im(f).)